# Pushwoosh web pushes in Drupal

Tags: drupal, push-notification, pushwoosh

I'm currently tying to get Pushwoosh working for browsers, such as Chrome, Safari and Firefox. The site I'm trying to do this for however is a Drupal 7. My browsers are enabled in the Pushwoosh dashboard. But somehow I can't get it to work.

What I've done so far:

- added the manifest.json file to my root and linked
- added the service workers to my root

I've add this piece of code to my html.tpl.php (temporary when it works I will add it in a cleaner way)

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <script src="https://cdn.pushwoosh.com/webpush/v3/pushwoosh-web-notifications.js" async></script>
    <script>
        var Pushwoosh = Pushwoosh || [];
        Pushwoosh.push(["init", {
          logLevel: 'error', // possible values: error, info, debug
          applicationCode: 'MY CODE',
          safariWebsitePushID: 'MY ID',
          defaultNotificationTitle: 'MY TITLE',
          defaultNotificationImage: 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/img/logo-medium.png',
          autoSubscribe: true,
          userId: 'user_id',
          tags: {
            'Name': 'John Smith'
          }
        }]);
    </script>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
  <?php print $gtm_datalayer; ?>
  <?php print $gtm_script; ?>
</head>
```

Everything shows up in the website, also my manifest.json is accesible.

However, I'm doing this on a staging environment which has http but a login is needed to acces and see the website. Is it possible that this restriction is causing the problem, did I go wrong in my setup or did I even forget some config?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Web pushes do not work with **http** out of the box, therefore **https** is required for the described solution to work.

However, Pushwoosh do have Chrome and Firefox http pushes, please take a look at this guide - http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/chrome-web-push-for-http-websites

Hope it will help!